# how to change the password on an AD user account that is both hidden and expired

Tags: c#, active-directory

If a domain AD user account is **hidden** * and **expired**, is there a way to change the password (not reset) in .net / c# ?

The code I have currently is using **System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement** and is essentially something like

```
using (var context = PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, server, container)
{
  var directoryUser = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, IdentityType.SamAccountName, username);
  directoryUser.ChangePassword(oldPassword, newPassword);
}
```

This works OK for users that the application service account can find, but some "hidden" users are in OUs that the application service account does not have read permissions to - and hence this fails with a null user.

I thought I would change it so that the **PrincipalContext** is established with the username and password of the user themselves (since they will have permissions to find themselves) - but often the account is expired by the time they come to change their password and so the FindByIdentity call fails as invalid credentials since the account is expired..

It's kind of a catch-22 where I can't find the user unless I search as the user, but I can't search as the user since they are expired, and I can only unexpire them by getting them to change their password.

If they have access to a workstation they can change their password using the Windows login controls but how to achieve this same level of functionality in c#?

**EDIT1:** I'm hoping for a solution that does not involve a service account with read-access to the hidden OUs - that would be difficult to achieve for various organization reasons.

Comment: Does it need to be done with **System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement**? I think I got something for u, but its made with DirectoryEntry only. (up to .net 2.0)

Comment: Did you try [CodeProject-AD](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18102/Howto-Almost-Everything-In-Active-Directory-via-C#40a) where it says *"Reset a User Password"*?

Comment: Reset a user is for the case where you have sufficient rights to force a password change on a user even if you don't know their previous password. What I want to do is allow users to change their password by supplying their old password and a new password - the password change takes place using the permissions and password the user already has to change their own passwords.

Comment: @manuchao To answer your 1st question :it does not have to use any particular library. The only constraint is that I will be invoking it from .net / c# since it is part of an asp.net website.

Comment: I do not think this is possible without a service account from .NET. I wrote a simple account managment module for web, and I needed a service account in that case. As the account is expired, you're not succeeding in validating the username/password combination.
What I did in that case was calling `RefreshExpiredPassword()` but you need a service account for that.

Comment: Yes, I couldn't find a way to do it in .NET however if a user has access to a workstation they can change their expired password using their old credentials using the system login controls - so the mechanisms exist at the Windows OS system level. It seems like every mechanism I find requires you to first search for the user in a way that it fails.

Comment: By "Hidden" you mean that the user that runs the code does not have read permissions to the user object?

Comment: Yes - that's exactly what I mean. The user running the code (application user) cannot find them due to lack of read permissions. If the end-user that wants to change their password is not expired I can use their own credentials to find themselves and change their password. However, sometimes the end-users delay too long and their account expires (require password at next login) and I cannot use their (end-user) own credentials to find them, nor my application-user.

Yes, this is a stupid situation but they have their reasons for restricting read permissions that I really can't get into.